# Transpose csv While Maintaining ID

Tags: python, csv, transpose

I have a fairly large *comma-separated* csv file with similar structure to:

```
ZipCd Var1 Var2 Var 3
12345 12    45   10
67890 13    23    5
  .   .     .    .
  .   .     .    .
  .   .     .    .
30010 99    17   6
```

For each ZipCd there are many Variables going to the right (approximately 250 total variables).  I would like for the following output to be produced:

```
ZipCd Var Value
12345 1    12
12345 2    45
12345 3    10
67890 1    13
67890 2    23
67890 3    5
30010 1    99
30010 2    17
30010 3    6
```

I have attempted the following:

```
with open("file.csv") as f, open("out.csv","w") as out:
   headers = next(f).split()[0:] #Get first row of original csv for headers and variable names
   for row in f:
      row = row.split(",") #split row into values delimited by comma
      ZipCd = row[0]
      Var1 = row[1]
      Var2 = row[2]
      Var3 = row[3]
      data = zip(headers, row[1:])
      for a, b in data:
         out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(ZipCd,a,b))
```

And that produces:

```
12345 ZipCd,Var1,Var2,Var3 12
67890 ZipCd,Var1,Var2,Var3 13
```

Any help in producing the desired output would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand: is your input file comma separated or space separated?

Comment: Comma, sorry.  Should have been more explicit.

Comment: I guessed it from the error you got!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mixup with the input file separator. It is clearly *comma*, but you're splitting the titles using no argument: the title is not split, and contains all fields, comma separated.

I'm proposing a solution

- using the `csv` module to read the input file, much cleaner.
- accepting as many variables as wished
- using `zip` like you did to "transpose" data
- the nice trick `for zipcd,*vars in cr` is used to get `zipcd` as the first field and `vars` as the remaining fields (called *Extended Iterable Unpacking* aka the "*target feature" as Martineau explained in another answer today)

code:

```
import csv

with open("file.csv") as f, open("out.csv","w") as out:
    cr = csv.reader(f)  # default separator is comma
    variable_names = next(cr)[1:]  # ignore first field in the title line
    out.write("ZipCd Var Value\n")
    for zipcd,*vars in cr:
        for vn,vv in zip(variable_names,vars):  # interleave data
            out.write("{} {} {}\n".format(zipcd,vn,vv))
```

sample input:

```
ZipCd,Var1,Var2,Var3
12345,12,45,10
67890,13,23,5
30010,99,17,6
```

Resulting output:

```
ZipCd Var Value
12345 Var1 12
12345 Var2 45
12345 Var3 10
67890 Var1 13
67890 Var2 23
67890 Var3 5
30010 Var1 99
30010 Var2 17
30010 Var3 6
```

Comment: With your code, when or how is zipcd assigned to the value in the first column of the input csv?

Comment: last bullet of my answer: `for zipcd,*vars in cr` assigns `zipcd`_and_ the vars.

Comment: OK, I was expecting a `zipcd = cr[0]` or similar declaration.  Still understanding the mechanics of `python`.

Comment: I try to answer questions using the most pythonic constructs (and explain them, as I sometimes have learned them the week before myself :))